# How to avoid setting a group mark's width and height twice?

Tags: vega

[This Vega specification](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgFY6AK1jcAdpAA04KO3TwA1tQBO3VjIAm2KABtG1fFuQBPBUsgB3RnpaGALAAY3iiJBSn8rjy8oQnQ9PUYZakNPWz10PEwcAG0lCFAIDKgZdFRkQ0hGTUZYG0zvVk0jfPwiEnJNdDsGZjZ2VlhkTXhZPGQZPDpu1CFaEfQAWjiEjrxYUgxYXs1SKZFC4slpOVSwAF8lAF0gyCN0Sx08Q2BIdBNqORwboyr5KG6jVlQZEpwARl3jhhNGofmAUpl0mVIHhLIQ8o8tDpCKUoX1unp4WBIWUoH0llcdjj7I5nDhrhRbqxMb9RG4AYSob4zJcyZAKR9qbT6TjMpAAGaMZ5XNmUzH2RDMPL7Hl7BncqGwUzZIyg8E867ZXL5BxORAKKDsqmGGl0oI4jU5MVM-yvEUc41chlHBmQVaGNXmhm8zVijohIwAGT61BYAH12BEUTLINIKvAxesSmaedCGt8+dxNKh3V6ytiZRlobCxcgAB69fpRgveAXIIwGR5+25ByLOZPVmNK275JuB4NhssVy65zLy6v5jswuH5CNydsF-mMOsNqC9lshvXz6ODvHCxX3buN5D+9cD8u76XVvZbvMjqFTsXoagWWi9KsdxGsQjsazJSCztx9X-CJfkgZ0r0LWt61VYCZEA8CIKgbhiHdSBul0S4EIgm4YPQyssKvSA1CsGcIkAu8IEvGUDlzKiMgI7wEFuZBVVzCcoR9fJS3fe9i3yEwZGQdBNB43k9G4DBI1ZfdlR7Y9m37RBQx3SsxxTNNqDFHU2zvSAZEYeNDDwTQqVom92O9S18msG9vAffiIiEkTbKgcTJIeLFXXiRJV3kvtWyU2cgKglc0J0VSXMgDSrWQPxLki-TDJwYzTJlOiIAYqB0FLFicxla4mKMMVuNtTMl0rR52G4AgJMgNSIRjeBmOsoCyt3R4ir5S50rATLICBEE8vVXT7MeTRkHgeLdL5bRs1ZN0jxPRTw0jerURkdFMQs9b8TJCjC246SmqKrjgqXetSLguqXN5UsACY92O4qzuXS7QNKvk+RmQxxjcOhRDW6Nf08wqxRsqAQvyPDupuwtLAeo7msecG7SNHA6X2nrR1op0djU65RqgT9kUvGjdiAA) shows a histogram of sepal lengths from the iris dataset. You'll see that whilst the data rectangle measures 400 x 400 pixels (light grey), that for the histogram measures 150 x 150 pixels (white).

The histogram's data rectangle is a group mark with a width and a height. It's necessary to set these values to ensure the x axis is correctly located at the bottom of the histogram's data rectangle.

I've also set the values of the local width and height signals, which override the global width and height signals. It's necessary to set these values because whilst the x and y scale ranges will accept a signal reference, they won't accept a [field value](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/types/#FieldValue), such as a property of the enclosing group mark. (Although even then, it's the *enclosing* group mark and not the *current* group mark.)

Setting a group mark's width and height twice -- once for the group mark and once for the signals -- isn't very DRY. What's the Vega idiom?

[One option](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgFY6AK1jcAdpAA04KO3TwA1tQBO3VjIAm2KABtG1fFuQBPBUsgB3RnpaGALAAY3iiJBSn8rjy8oQnQ9PUYZakNPWz10PEwcAG0lCFAIDKgZdFRkQ0hGTUZYG0zvVk0jfPwiEnJNdDsGZjZ2VlhkTXhZPGQZPDpu1CFaEfQAWjiEjrxYUgxYXs1SKZFC4slpOVSwAF8lAF0gyCN0Sx08Q2BIdBNqORwboyr5KG6jVlQZEpwARl3jhhNGofmAUpl0mVIHhLIQ8o8tDpCKUobBTNkjKDwWU0pBsrl8g4nIgFFAKLdWPCwL9RG4ATsIXiclSfMg-JdXpByR8qTS6QywEcBZAgSDDNicZCcd4YXD8ojWMigtKoH1unoqVKVar+p0rgKVfZHM4cNc0fdboTjST6dqob4zJdTZBzRjqmzHZBbXaMpAAGaMZ5XLkUll2RDMPL7H17A0Zb2G1biuMQlNQ-EsjohIwAGT61BYAH12BEUTGXTouiz1iVlT7oQ1vn7uJpUMmY6mO1DZSzkAAPXr9MtdqAB5BGAyPLO3PORZx1rsu9GWqfIbOzguIQv9weXNM4hMdrWLnv5EtyBcd-2MceTqDT3P5+f76WQHd9J1gM3Lqqr9dPrd3yHaMR0PGNjyvU9HnQagLFoXph0XBVCHYaxkkgc83FJDCIl+SAhRHX0xwnLEcJkLCCMIqBuGIcVIG6XRLkowiblIhih2YkdIDUKwzwiLCX0yECYwOF9hOlTicRdeBbmQLEXwgw0M3yPtEO1aFYRZEwZGQdBNDUxNuAwUtnVdFd7zXGcAO3AcPy9S9DUbagw2tAzXxkRh4CpPBNEpMSHLKRT3OZfJrACqSoOMCJdP08KoT0Iz0BMr9ICTP8rLnLdz2w4i73onRgLizJICclkHX8IrfQ8rzDB8vyY3EnFJKhdA+zk9sfTNGSjBZVTORbG8h0edhuAIIz7IU6TZNC7CBrsx4er9S5GrKZritFeTwMEqBIpK5B4A5bb-W0NtnTSiz-0y4tSzA9S1W4DV9RYj89VNbbitU0zut6nKbwnPjyImqioD7AAmYMEGmx4+tHP68vPPD+r9P0ZkMcY3DoURbvLNCUshnqZs5XL8nY5bKqkyxwa+qGoDCslQ2iFa7SZ6UWaEtNRJVFbOfjOtrl25CvUOEBdiAA) is to add an enclosing group mark, within which the local width and height signals are set, and modifying the enclosed data rectangle group mark to use a signal field value, rather than a literal field value. However, this seems unnecessarily verbose.